# Paginação com método genérico

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, paginação, genéricos

Estou tentando criar um método genérico para paginação, tentei fazer como o código abaixo, porém ao usar `Skip` preciso ter um `orderby` e não estou sabendo como fazer.

```
public IQueryable<TEntity> GetPaginacao(int PageStart, int PageSize)
        {
            return Db.Set<TEntity>()
                .Take(PageSize)
                .Skip(PageStart * PageSize)
                .AsNoTracking();

        }
```

Erro:

> The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não precisa reinventar a roda. Apenas [instale este pacote](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PagedList.EntityFramework/).

Uso:

```
var pagina = 1;
var registros = 50;
var selecao = db.Entidade.ToPagedList(pagina, registros);
```

Ou ainda:

```
var selecao = await db.Entidade.ToPagedListAsync(pagina, registros);
```

Acho que pro seu caso vai ter que ordenar por alguma coisa:

```
var selecao = db.Entidade.OrderBy(e => e.Id).ToPagedList(pagina, registros);
```

Comment: O PagedList retorna um tipo IPagedList, como eu converto isso para IQueryable ou para IEnumerable ? ou seria melhor trabalhar com List() ?

Comment: [`IPagedList` implementa `IEnumerable`](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList/IPagedList.cs). Não deve impactar seu código antigo.

Comment: Alterando o código original para `return Db.Set<TEntity>().ToPagedList(1, 10);` um erro é apresentado **Cannot implicitly convert type 'PagedList.IPagedList<TEntity>' to 'System.Linq.IQueryable<TEntity>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)** tentei alterar para `public IList<TEntity> GetPaginacao(int PageStart, int PageSize) return Db.Set<TEntity>().ToPagedList(1, 10).ToList();` e o seguinte erro é exibido **The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'.**

Comment: Ah, sim. Alterei a resposta. Eu não faria este método `GetPaginacao`. Ele é desnecessário, até porque a intenção de você envelopar o procedimento é justamente de não usar `Skip()` e `Take()` o tempo todo, mas agora não tem mais motivo.

Comment: acho que entendi, mas estou com algumas dúvidas com relação a performance, sempre que encontramos exemplos de paginação, é algo parecido com isto: `var x = db.entidade.GetAll(); return x.ToPagedList(1, 10);` neste caso, quando eu chamo o GetAll() eu não estou trazendo todos os registros do banco?

Comment: Esse exemplo não é bom mesmo. É só o exemplo inicial.